# Setting up JSFiddle with CoffeeScript + React?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, jsfiddle

How can I set up JSFiddle to work with CoffeeScript and React?

I would like to code React examples using CoffeeScript and expect it to run.

I've tried setting the language to CoffeeScript on the left sidebar, and including the React libs, but that does not work.

Any pointers on how I could get Coffee+React to work with JSFiddle?

Comment: are there any error messages shown? got a link?

Answer (score 4):

From `<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>`, which is included in the playground:

```
(function() {
  var tag = document.querySelector(
    'script[type="application/javascript;version=1.7"]'
  );
  if (!tag || tag.textContent.indexOf('window.onload=function(){') !== -1) {
    alert('Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle');
  }
  tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/jsx;harmony=true');
  tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace(/^\/\/<!\[CDATA\[/, '');
})();
```

The reason is that you are using the playground with `jsx`, and as FB restricted the setting to JS 1.7 I guess they are using Babel to compile it down to js.

So if you use the non-`jsx` link, and change the syntax to Coffee and modify the JS/CS file, you are good to go.

Here is a working copy: https://jsfiddle.net/9gnkLgex/